# no module named msilib.schema error in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, portability

I am running a python file in UBUNTU, it shows an error that no module named `msilib.schema` 
My question is `msi` is used for Microsoft, right? can we use it in `ubuntu` ? and how ?

this is my whole project and i want to run it in ubuntu....https://www.dropbox.com/s/xwgg4i3gnv1u2cw/clovis.rar

Comment: how did you get the error, what exactly were you doing?

Comment: MSI is really specific to Windows. It's normal that it dosen't work under Linux. What are you attempting to do? You should use a Linux compatible way to install softwares.

Comment: my file is on www.notepad.cc/testpy.....I have a testcase developed by someone I want to run it using UBUNTU. but while running it is showing an error : from msilib.schema import RadioButton, checkBox .....ImportError: No module maned msilib.schema

Comment: As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msilib.html) says that lib is Windows platform specific.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/msilib.html is for windows only

Comment: Migration from one platform to another often requires you to replace functionality not available on the receiving platform. This is one such case - the code was written for Windows, and a required library is simply not available on Ubuntu.

Comment: yes, msilib is for windows only, I have uploaded my file on www.notepad.cc/testpy...how can I use it here in ubuntu? error is msilib.schema module not found

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msilib.html) says that lib is Windows platform specific.

You should see how to write your test cases under Linux using adapted tools. There are many ways to develop GUI, [PyQt](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) for instance provide a lot of helpful tools.

For testing you have [py.test](http://pytest.org/latest/) suite.

Comment: done...I found the solution ...we dont need msilib in ubuntu at all

Answer (score 1):

`msilib` is a python module built for the Windows platform, as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msilib.html) shows. Therefore, you should not try and import it in a python script which you run on an Ubuntu platform.

Comment: I think that is well covered in the comments

Comment: Yes, I just added it as an answer to help this question for being accepted. Is that not the proper workflow?

Comment: (if not, I'll gladly remove the answer, I am not seeking rep here)

Comment: what is the option or solution for ubuntu ?

Comment: Solution for what? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Depends indeed on what you're trying to do. There is always a workaround, especially in python.

Comment: this is my whole project and i want to run it in ubuntu....https://www.dropbox.com/s/xwgg4i3gnv1u2cw/clovis.rar

Comment: @user3754938 - you should not expect us to download you "whole project" and examine it. This is just not what this site is for.

Comment: yeah , I know, but this was for who wants to learn ,if one does not wish so , he/she can ignore it